# no funciona la API Fetch en javascript, cuando hago fetch a mi API REST en Heroku

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, heroku

Tengo un problema con la **api fetch** de **js** cuando intento hacer una petición `get` a una `api rest` básica que realice en **node** y la desplegué en **heroku**, para probar esta api la corri en **postman** y funciona perfectamente cuando quiero hacer un `fetch` o intento llamarla con **axios** no funciona, el **api rest** no tiene ningún error, el código de la petición es el siguiente:

```js
fetch('https://gimnasio-app.herokuapp.com/',{mode:"no-cors"})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Sin embargo cuando uso la función con, por ejemplo, `jsonplaceholder` si funciona **(sin el`{mode: "no-cors"}`  porque por algún motivo me demanda poner ese modo)**, no se si habrá que hacer alguna configuración en **heroku** o que, para que vean el código de **backend**.

> Aquí mismo dejo el repositorio https://github.com/elias-dev/gimnasio-rest

Comment: has intentando sin usar el mode: "no-cors" ? y ver que te arroja en el log ?

Comment: si quito el "no-cors" sale esto: **Access to fetch at 'https://gimnasio-app.herokuapp.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Comment: imagine eso, puedes usar el módulo de `cors` para `express` o usar el siguiente midleware, 
```js
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Parece ser que axios fetch tiene un problema en modo no cors.

Comment: Gracias!, ese código que me pasaste funcionó, soy nuevo con express y node, ahora lo tendré en cuenta, también fue culpa de heroku que demora en subirse y no se podía obtener rápidamente el **get**, y también soy nuevo en stackoverflow debería eliminar la pregunta? saludos!

Comment: que bueno que funciono :D,puedes indicar que ya se soluciono agregando [Solucionado] :)

Comment: Para mas sencillo usa [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) tal como dice @kiramishima

Comment: @kiramishima Aquí no se añade nada al título para indicar que se solucionó. Si tienen la respuesta, se pone como respuesta y se marca como aceptada. Incluso si la respuesta la pone quien pregunta. Si fue tu comentario, ponlo como respuesta y que el OP la acepte.

Comment: Si alguien aquí tiene dudas sobre cómo preguntar, responder o usar el sitio, por favor no duden en pasar por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio. No recomendemos formas de hacer las cosas que se desaconsejan o hacen más difícil el uso del sitio a otros.

Comment: Si, pase por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) pero cuando la respuesta esta en los comentarios no sabría como terminar el post, ya un usuario me brindo otra respuesta que no sabia, que era instalar cors de express ambas soluciones dieron en el blanco saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser un problema de cors.

Puedes agregar en tu servidor:

Opción 1 - para permitir todas las peticiones desde cualquier origen

```
app.use(cors())
```

Opción 2 - para delimitar desde que url quieres que se hagan las peticiones

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials:true,
  origin:[<Lista de URLs de donde haras las peticiones>]
}))
```